# How to read a data from a csv file and write that data to certain rows in a new csv file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, csv

I want to read in one file and write to certain columns in the other

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;



namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("AEJoinerDataTemplate.csv"))
            // using streamwriter to write to a text file
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("AutoEnrolment.csv"))
            // using streamreader to read a text file 
            {
                while ((txtline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
```

Comment: are you writing to an existing csv, by that i mean does the csv have data in it already?

Comment: consider searching for a csv helper library from nuget.

Comment: yeah it has headings in it already

Answer (score 0):

A very flexible way would be to first put your records into objects and then write those fields of the objects you would like to output to a new file.

You could for example use the library below to read objects from a file and write objects to a file.

[FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net)